# NLTK CorpusReader for Indian language

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk

Trying to get NLTK to do analysis on a Punjabi corpus downloaded from an Indian government research site, the script is Gurmikhi. My primary goal is to get word frequency distributions on the entire corpus, so the aim here is to get all the words tokenized.

My issue seems to be with how NLTK is reading the text because when I use Python's built in methods:

```
    with open("./Punjabi_Corpora/Panjabi_Monolingual_TextCorpus_Sample.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = [line for line in f]
        fulltxt = "".join(lines)
        print(fulltxt.split)
```

Result (not perfect, but workable):

```
    ['\ufeffਜਤਿੰਦਰ', 'ਸਾਬੀ', 'ਜਲੰਧਰ,', '10', 'ਜਨਵਰੀ-ਦੇਸ਼-ਵਿਦੇਸ਼', 'ਦੇ',...]
```

However when using NLTK, as such:

```
    from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader
    corpus_root = "./Punjabi_Corpora"
    corpus = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root,"Panjabi Monolingual_TextCorpus_Sample.txt")
    corpus.words('Panjabi_Monolingual_TextCorpus_Sample.txt')
```

I get the following

```
    ['ਜਤ', 'ਿੰ', 'ਦਰ', 'ਸ', 'ਾ', 'ਬ', 'ੀ', 'ਜਲ', 'ੰ', 'ਧਰ', ...]
```

Here, NLTK thinks that each character glyph is a full word, I guess it's Indic script knowledge isn't quite there yet :)

From what I could surmise based on the NLTK docs, the issue has to do with the Unicode encoding, it seems there is some disagreement between the file and NLTK... I've been tinkering and Googling as far as I am able and have hit the wall. 
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. According to the doc, PlainTextCorpusReader is a reader set for ascii inputs. So it is not surprising that it does not work properly.

I am not a pro on this subject, but I tried to use the IndianCorpusReader instead with your dataset and it seems working :

```
from nltk.corpus import IndianCorpusReader
corpus = IndianCorpusReader("./Punjabi_Corpora", "Panjabi Monolingual_TextCorpus_Sample.txt")
print(corpus.words('Panjabi Monolingual_TextCorpus_Sample.txt'))
```

And the output :

```
['ਜਤਿੰਦਰ', 'ਸਾਬੀ', 'ਜਲੰਧਰ', '10', 'ਜਨਵਰੀ-ਦੇਸ਼-ਵਿਦੇਸ਼', ...]
```

Tested on Python 3.

Comment: Haha! I knew I should've called captain obvious!
I'll chalk that one up to too many trees, not enough forest.
Thanks!